# Is it possible to secure an Azure Function within an Azure AD B2C user journey using a function key

Tags: azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I understand how to secure the function using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-rest-api but that is overkill for my function as only ADB2C should be calling it.

How do I use a function key to secure it or is it not possible?

Comment: Congrats on your first post and welcome!

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/security-concepts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just put the function key in the ServiceURL (as azure function provides), and set the rest api technical profile up for no authentication.